# If row start ## or # dont print this row but 1st row must be printed everytime

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, printing, awk

I need some help, if row start with ##  don't print this all columns for this rows and if it is not start with this, print $0. But first row must be printed everytime.

I tried :

```
awk '{for (i=0;i<=NF;i++);{if ($i == "##*") print ""; else print $0}}' 788613_v1.vcf > fedulka.tsv
```

Could you help me please?

INPUT:

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.1
##INFO=<ID=VARB,Number=A,Type=Float,Description="Variant Hypothesis bias in prediction.">
##INFO=<ID=genes,Number=.,Type=String,Description="Overlapping gene name">
#CHROM  POS ID  REF
chr13   32890572    .   G
chr13   32890650    COSM35423   G
chr13   32893219    COSM23939   G
```

OUTPUT:

```
 ##fileformat=VCFv4.1

    #CHROM  POS ID  REF
    chr13   32890572    .   G
    chr13   32890650    COSM35423   G
    chr13   32893219    COSM23939   G
```

Comment: Show your simplified input and expected output, otherwise it's not clear.

Comment: Sorry it was mistake for my document. For this example is Ok to print  $0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this,

```
$ cat file
##title
foo
bar
#foo
##foobar
$ awk 'NR==1{print; next}{if ($1~/^#/) {next;} else {print}}' file
##title
foo
bar
```

It skip the lines which starts with `#` except the first line and print all the remaining lines.

Answer (score 1):

Just print the first and then check either the line starts with one or two `#`. If that does not happen, condition is true so the line is automatically printed.

```
awk 'NR==1{print; next} !/^#{1,2}/' file
```

See sample:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print; next} !/^#{1,2}/' a
##fileformat=VCFv4.1
chr13   32890572    .   G
chr13   32890650    COSM35423   G
chr13   32893219    COSM23939   G
```

Comment: It is really nice and easy.. Thank you so much

Comment: Nice to read that. No need to use `if/else`, as this will handle alone.

Comment: @FilipZembol strange, why do you want `#CHROM  POS ID  REF` to be in the output? I don't understand the logic.

Comment: it is for another example, I join two things to one and I separate codes, which you wrote.. At first I need only chr13 etc... and after that I need first column and #chrom etc...It works...

Comment: `paste` will join two files in the same order